# Run ocaml from command line

Tags: ocaml

How can I run ocaml from the command prompt in windows. 
Whenever I try

```
ocaml puzzle.ml
```

I get the error

```
'ocaml' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I used to be able to use just this line of code to compile and execute the program, but I recently had to do a system restore and have lost this functionality.

The path variable in environment variables is

```
C:\OCaml\emacs-23.3\bin;
C:\OCaml\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;
C:\Ruby193\bin
```

I got it working. Just a reminder to anyone who has the same issue. After you edit your path variable or install something that does, make sure to restart your command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add it to your PATH.

1.) System -> advanced system settings -> 'Advanced' tab -> Environment Variables

2.) Under 'system variables' -> select 'Path'

3.) See if Ocaml is listed somewhere in there.

If not you will have to add it manually.

Comment: Where is Ocaml installed on your computer?

Comment: There is C:\OCaml\emacs-23.3\bin;C:\OCaml\bin; in the path variable

Comment: Oh then I'm not sure what's causing this issue. I was certain it was an issue with Path. If no one else provides a solution I would just reinstall Ocaml which will most likely fix this.

Comment: I have done that multiple times and still getting the same error

Comment: Could you try adding C:\OCaml\lib; to your path as well.

Comment: still giving the same error that ocaml is not a recognized command

Comment: I cant get any ocaml compilers to work such as ocamlc. Is there another way to develop in ocaml that I could use

Comment: Thanks for your help I can't believe i forgot to restart my cmd after editing the path variable

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. To answer your earlier question, yes you can use an online IDE. This is what I use: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_ocaml_online.php